# Laravel authorized user first

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am building a Laravel application, and my task was to get the list of admin(site-team) users but authorized user has to be first in the list.

Here is my solution:

```
$this->team = User::team()
            ->except(Auth::user())
            ->oldest()
            ->get();

$this->team->prepend(Auth::user());
```

Here I'm fetching only site-team members excluding currently authorized user and then just prepending auth user to the results.

I was wondering is there a better and cleaner solution for this?

Comment: I think it's really good solution

Comment: This should probably be a https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ question. Good practice questions tend to be rather opinionated and can be considered off-topic.

Comment: @apokryfos when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)